# Quickblox - check content database IOS

Tags: ios, database, quickblox

For my app I am using quickblox. I am trying to upload a picture to the content database of quickblox. Now I need to check if the current user is already in the database with the image named personal. If so I want the ID of the entry.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the [Set the chat/Avatar in QuickBlox QBUUser in iOS Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620666/set-the-chat-avatar-in-quickblox-qbuuser-in-ios-chat)

And also QBUUser has a property blobID, which you can associate with profile avatar in Custom Objects. So when you want to check that selected user has an avatar, check for blobID == nil